# Launch System DBus Daemon

Tags: 20.04, dbus

I want to use an application that requires a system-wide dbus daemon to function. I'm doing this in Gitpod (the default Docker image is currently based on Ubuntu 20.04).

Dbus and dbus-daemon are installed. The process control system is [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). I am now trying to manually launch a system-wide dbus daemon but keep failing because anything I find on the topic is based on systemd being the init system. The [dbus-launch](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html) utility appears to be intended for session dbus only. [Dbus-broker](https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker) seemed like it might be helpful but I can't install it because it is no longer available through apt for 20.04 and I run into a cryptic error when building it from source.

My approach might be bogus. There may be a system dbus running that I could use but I don't know how to check the status because again, anything I find on the topic presumes systemd is the init system.

I'm clearly not an expert. Could someone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: From `apt show supervisor`: "Supervisor is a system for controlling and maintaining process state, similar to what init does, **but not intended as an init replacement**."

Comment: @user535733 `ps -p 1 -o comm=` returns `supervisor`. That's why I wrote it is the init system. I updated my post and rephrased it to "process control system".